# Use Seaborn Plot Data based on values in other Columns in Python

Tags: python, seaborn

I'm trying to plot data based on values in two to three other columns. The below code works if I take out  `& df[df.Age > 50]`. Is there a way to adjust the code to work? Thank you!

```py
plt.figure(figsize = (15, 5))
plt.title(f"KDE Plot:", fontsize = 30, fontweight = 'bold')
ax = sns.kdeplot(
    df[df.OpenedLCInd== 1 ] & df[df.Age > 50]['APlusCreditTier'].dropna(),
    label = 'Opened Letter Check',
    lw = 2,
    legend = True
)
plt.legend = True
ax1 = sns.kdeplot(
    df[df.OpenedLCInd == 0]['APlusCreditTier'].dropna(), 
    label = 'No Open Letter Check', 
    lw = 2, legend = True
)
plt.tight_layout()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conditional is wrong in the first `kdeplot`, it should be:

```py
df[df.OpenedLCInd.eq(1) & df.Age.gt(50)]['APlusCreditTier'].dropna()
```

or

```py
df[(df.OpenedLCInd== 1) & (df.Age > 50)]['APlusCreditTier'].dropna()
```

See the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html#how-do-i-filter-specific-rows-from-a-dataframe) for more information on subsetting your data.